# Get value from controller and show alert as atleast one value should be active

Tags: jquery, laravel-4

```
$selected_subcats =  EstablishmnetSubcategories::Join('establishments','establishments.id','=','establishment_subcategories.establishment_id')->where('establishment_subcategories.created_by',Auth::User()->id)->get(array('establishment_subcategories.status as sub_status'));
```

This is my controller code and output of it

[`{"status":1},{"status":1},{"status":1},{"status":1},{"status":1},{"status":1},{"status":1},{"status":0}]`

I have a condition like, i need to check the status from controller, i have a requirement like atleast one status value should be 0(active),  i want a jquery validation in frontend that should alert me that atleast one status should be 0(active) on clicking the button . can anyone please help, how this can be done..thank you

Below code is my view code

```
<td><a href="javascript:void;"  class="label label-warning">{{$p->sub_status == 0 ? '<span class="label label-warning">Unpublish </span>' : '<span class="label label-warning">publish </span>'}}</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your query to return the number of categories that have a status of 0 - active

```
$activeCats =  EstablishmnetSubcategories::Join('establishments','establishments.id','=','establishment_subcategories.establishment_id')
->where('establishment_subcategories.created_by',Auth::User()->id)
->where('establishment_subcategories.status',0)
->count();
```

html:

```
<td><a href="javascript:void;"  class="label label-warning">{{$activeCats  > 0 ? '<span class="label label-warning">Unpublish </span>' : '<span class="label label-warning">publish </span>'}}</a></td>
```